# SYS_REFCURSOR will reduce the performance in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am having two table `catalog` and `catalog_elements.`

A catalog can contain many catalog elements.

I have a functionality, where I need to list all elements associated with the one catalog and top of a same page I need to show the catalog name and catalog comment (one catalog can contain one comment).

my DBA given a stored procedure, where putting inner join and selecting the records like below,

```
C.cat_name, C.cat_comment, CE.cat_ele_id, CE.cat_ele_date

   [C means catalog, CE means catalog Elements]
```

But I like to use a second `SYS_REFCURSOR` to select a catalog details, to avoid the repeated Tuples of catalog details in each row

Can anyone suggest the best solution for this (in the terms of performance) ?

The below sp having two cursor which i like to propose to DBA.

(I like remove the cat_name and cat_comment from the select query by using the second cursor to fetch catalog data)

SP Code template is below:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE SP_GET_Cat_CatEle_DTL(
          P_CATALOG_ID NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
          P_RECORDSET  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
          P_CATALOG_RECORD OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
          ) AS

BEGIN
  OPEN P_RECORDSET FOR

    select cat_name, cat_comment, cat_ele_id, cat_ele_date from  cat inner join
    cat_ele on cat.id = cat_ele_id where cat.id = P_CATALOG_ID

  OPEN P_CATALOG_RECORD FOR
    SELECT * FROM CATALOG_MASTER WHERE CATALOG_ID = P_CATALOG_ID;

END SP_GET_Cat_CatEle_DTL;
```

Comment: show the actual SP please.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of resource occupation and time consumtion, using only one cursor is the best solution. The query would be a bit more complex but in your condition it should not be a problem.

Comment: Actually, i removed some lines in that select query, the real select query is doing inner join with 5 tables.So the the output records will  contain minimum 100 rows and each row will contain the 3 column of same values.My concern is like this repeated data would take some time when data transfer from db server to application server.

Comment: @sathishkumar can you show the real SPs please? Yours and the dba's one

Comment: I can't show the real project sp sir, so please give your email id i can send to you